# Empty a dataframe created by reactiveValues() after pressing actionbutton

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple shiny app which visualizes a network below: When you click in a node a reactive dataframe is created and displayed in the app. But then I want to press the action button and empty this table. When I select another node the table will be created again. I used `reactiveValues()` and an observer for this but my app is breaking down.

```
library(igraph)
library(visNetwork)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)
library(shinydashboard)
#dataset
id<-c("articaine","benzocaine","etho","esli")
label<-c("articaine","benzocaine","etho","esli")
node<-data.frame(id,label)

from<-c("articaine","articaine","articaine",
        "articaine","articaine","articaine",
        "articaine","articaine","articaine")
to<-c("benzocaine","etho","esli","benzocaine","etho","esli","benzocaine","etho","esli")
title<-c("SCN1A","SCN1A","SCN1A","SCN2A","SCN2A","SCN2A","SCN3A","SCN3A","SCN3A")

edge<-data.frame(from,to,title)


#app

ui <- dashboardPage(

  # Generate Title Panel at the top of the app
  dashboardHeader(
  title="Network Visualization App"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    actionButton("update","Update data")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6,
           DTOutput('tbl')
           ),
    column(width = 6,
           visNetworkOutput("network")) #note that column widths in a fluidRow should sum to 12
  )
  )
) #end of fluidPage


server <- function (input, output, session){

  output$network <- renderVisNetwork({
    visNetwork(nodes = node,edge) %>% 
      visOptions(highlightNearest=TRUE, 
                 nodesIdSelection = TRUE) %>%
      #allow for long click to select additional nodes
      visInteraction(multiselect = TRUE) %>%
      visIgraphLayout() %>% 

      #Use visEvents to turn set input$current_node_selection to list of selected nodes
      visEvents(select = "function(nodes) {
                Shiny.onInputChange('current_node_selection', nodes.nodes);
                ;}")

  })
 rt<-reactive({
   colnames(edge)<- c("Target 1","Target 2","Shared Drug")
   edge %>% 
     filter((edge[,1] %in% input$current_node_selection)|(edge[,2] %in% input$current_node_selection))
 })
 ####WRONG APPROACH

 #rt<-reactiveValues({
 #  colnames(edge)<- c("Target 1","Target 2","Shared Drug")
 #  edge %>% 
  #   filter((edge[,1] %in% input$current_node_selection)|(edge[,2] %in% input$current_node_selection))
 #})

 #observeEvent(input$update, {
 # rt = rt[FALSE,]
 #})
 #####


  #render data table restricted to selected nodes
  output$tbl <- renderDT(
    rt()
  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a combination of reactiveValue, observe and observeEvent. You will createa reactiveValue that will be used inside the table's filter, that will be attributed via observeEvent. Then, you use observe to update this filter to NULL when the button is pressed. See below for example. If you want to do the same to the graph, you just need to apply the same logic.

```
library(igraph)
library(visNetwork)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)
library(shinydashboard)
#dataset
id<-c("articaine","benzocaine","etho","esli")
label<-c("articaine","benzocaine","etho","esli")
node<-data.frame(id,label)

from<-c("articaine","articaine","articaine",
        "articaine","articaine","articaine",
        "articaine","articaine","articaine")
to<-c("benzocaine","etho","esli","benzocaine","etho","esli","benzocaine","etho","esli")
title<-c("SCN1A","SCN1A","SCN1A","SCN2A","SCN2A","SCN2A","SCN3A","SCN3A","SCN3A")

edge<-data.frame(from,to,title)


#app

ui <- dashboardPage(

  # Generate Title Panel at the top of the app
  dashboardHeader(
    title="Network Visualization App"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    actionButton("update","Update data")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 6,
             DTOutput('tbl')
      ),
      column(width = 6,
             visNetworkOutput("network")) #note that column widths in a fluidRow should sum to 12
    )
  )
) #end of fluidPage


server <- function (input, output, session){

  # initialize reactiveValues
  rv <- reactiveValues()


  output$network <- renderVisNetwork({
    visNetwork(nodes = node,edge) %>% 
      visOptions(highlightNearest=TRUE, 
                 nodesIdSelection = TRUE) %>%
      #allow for long click to select additional nodes
      visInteraction(multiselect = TRUE) %>%
      visIgraphLayout() %>% 

      #Use visEvents to turn set input$current_node_selection to list of selected nodes
      visEvents(select = "function(nodes) {
                Shiny.onInputChange('current_node_selection', nodes.nodes);
                ;}")

  })

  # Attribute the input value to the reactive variable
  observeEvent(input$current_node_selection, {
    rv$data <- input$current_node_selection
  })

  # watch the reset button and attribute NULL if pressed
  observe({
    input$update
    rv$data <- NULL
  })

  # filter based on reactive variable
  rt<-reactive({
    colnames(edge)<- c("Target 1","Target 2","Shared Drug")
    edge %>% 
      filter((edge[,1] %in% rv$data) | (edge[,2] %in% rv$data))
  })


  output$tbl <- renderDT({
     rt()
    })  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```